# Trying to build ruby on visual studio with zlib

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-2013, build, zlib

I'm trying to build ruby on visual studio with zlib and I'm having problems with it.

I have prepared everything to build it but I don't know how to specify where the zlib library and headers are.

I have the source code in $(ProjectDir)/..
I am buildin in $(ProjectDir)/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)
I build with command line, and I have it like this

```
mkdir $(Platform)\$(Configuration)
cd $(Platform)\$(Configuration)\
..\..\..\win32\configure.bat --target=i386-mswin32 --prefix=$(ProjectDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\bin
```

If I go to ext/zlib, I can execute

```
extconf.rb --with-zlib-lib=$(ProjectDir)..\..\zlib-1.2.8\zlib-1.2.8\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\lib --with-zlib-include=$(ProjectDir)..\..\zlib-1.2.8
```

and creates the makefile correcly, but I don't know how to pass zlib lib
and include paths to the configuration script.

I have tried with

```
..\..\..\win32\configure.bat --target=i386-mswin32 --prefix=$(ProjectDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\bin --with-zlib-lib=$(ProjectDir)..\..\zlib-1.2.8\zlib-1.2.8\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\lib --with-zlib-include=$(ProjectDir)..\..\zlib-1.2.8
```

but that doesn't works

I suppose it has something to do with the '--with-ext="a,b,..."' option or with the "--path" that is specified in the help command, but I don't know how to specify it and the documentation is really bad.

I would be very gratefull if you could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions below are for Ruby 2.2.5 – if you want to build some other version or use different folder paths, change accordingly. I used these to successfully build Ruby 2.2.5 and 2.3.1 from source with zlib using VS2013 Community Update 5 on Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

- Create folders:

  ```
  C:\ruby-2.2.5\build
  C:\ruby-2.2.5\src
  ```
- Untar `ruby-2.2.5.tar.gz` and put the sources in `C:\ruby-2.2.5\src`
- Unzip the zlib distribution archive (`zlib128-dll.zip`) into `C:\zlib128-dll`
- Run Developer Command Prompt for VS2013, then run:

  ```
  SET INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\zlib128-dll\include
  SET LIB=%LIB%;C:\zlib128-dll\lib
  SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\zlib128-dll

  cd C:\ruby-2.2.5\build
  ..\src\win32\configure.bat
  nmake
  nmake DESTDIR=C:/ruby-2.2.5 install
  ```
- Done. You should now have a fully working, zlib-enabled, Ruby build in `C:\ruby-2.2.5\usr`.

Comment: Great stuff! Information on building Ruby with Visual Studio is scarce - much appreciated. I wonder what (if any) OpenSSL package to install in order to get a Ruby build which features SSL support...

Comment: Obtain a precompiled OpenSSL package (or build it yourself), change the environment variables accordingly, and you're good to go. I downloaded v1.1.0b from [here](http://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-openssl/) and it worked.

        SET INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\zlib128-dll\include;C:\Win32OpenSSL-1_0_2d\include


        SET LIB=%LIB%;C:\zlib128-dll\lib;C:\Win32OpenSSL-1_0_2d\lib;C:\Win32OpenSSL-1_0_2d\lib\VC


        SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\zlib128-dll;C:\Win32OpenSSL-1_0_2d\bin